# Using kerberos delegation in WCF across domains and passing ClientCredentials

Tags: wcf, cross-domain, kerberos, delegation

I've got a client app in one domain (Domain1) that needs to access a WCF service on an app server in another domain (Domain2) (with no trust). Users have to enter their Domain2 credentials into the client app. This WCF service needs to connect to a database on another server in Domain2.

I pass the credentials using ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential. I've got delegation enabled for the user and the app server (also the db server but I don't think that's necessary). I've got the server and client set up for delegation in their app configs. However it seems that when it connects it is only using impersonation (not delegation) when it hits the app server and so I get an anonymous access error from the db.

I suspected this could be because you can't use kerberos delegation across domains. So I tried running the client app in Domain2 and got the same error. But when I take out the credential setting (with ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential) and run the client in Domain2 (so it will use the logged in user credentials) then it works.

It seems to me that it's probably because it's not passing a kerberos token to the WCF service but is passing the username and password. But surely it should be able to pass the username and password to the web service and connect and then be authenticated in that domain?

I've had a look around but haven't found anyone else who has had this issue with cross domain delegation using ClientCredentials.

Hopefully someone can help me.